# iTunes playing album tracks in wrong order

Tags: itunes

When playing a specific album, iTunes plays the third track ninth. When checking 'Get info' the track is clearly designated as track 3 of 10. Nothing I do moves it to the correct position in the album order. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the order constant? Maybe your shuffle is on.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes version 12.5.3 lists this as a potential problem in iTunes that has been fixed.

> - Fixes an issue where albums may play in an unexpected order

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1814

Comment: Would you please add a link to the source of your assertion? Thanks!

Comment: @Jaime For content like this where the canonical official source is trivial to find, it's encouraged for editors to add such information to an answer. Of course, the original author of the answer should have included a reference, but instead of asking for a reference you may as well add it yourself.

Comment: I will in the future, just thought the comment would be "educational" being the first answer from a new user. But educating by example is better yet, thanks George.